# Unable to do import java class from my project on build.gradle

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I'm facing an issue in importing the java class of my project in the `build.gradle` file on a task. Its throwing an exception when I try to run the task.

Kindly find the task I created for it below,

```
task validateAttributes() {
    doLast {
         import com.xyz.Users
    }
}
```

When we do `./gradlew validateAttributes`, we are getting the following error on the terminal.

```
Could not compile build file '/PATH_TO_FILE/build.gradle'.
> startup failed:
           import com.xyz.Users
           ^
1 error
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 758ms
```

Kindly let me know if there is something I'm missing

Comment: There could be many reasons for this to occur. If you can please elaborate more into question. 
1. Check if you have internet connection /  connectivity to repo which its trying to connect.
2. Check proxy

This is what I can imagine as of now.

Comment: Hi @VinitMore,

The connectivity is good. I'm trying to import the java file from the same project when I'm trying to access in `build.gradle` file. Kindly let me know details you require additionally.

Comment: Check if 

depedencies {implementation 'group:artifact:version'}

is defined correctly. Also check what gradle version are you using. Before gradle 4.x it was Groovy, after 5.x its Kotlin